# VS Web Test Load, Distribution and Iterations

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, web-testing

In this case, I have created several webtest scripts, and added them to a load test (distributed by expected use).

What I would like to do is send a user load (500 for example) where all users run at the same time, each user is given only a single script to run and complete, then the test is finished. One iteration for each user.

I am finding that iterations are not user based but test based, so only one user and test is completed when selecting a Test Iterations value of 1 for 500 users.
Is there a user based iteration setting or some other way to accomplish my intended test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The test settings you have used are not at all clear from your question. However assuming you want to start 500 test cases at the same time and stop after they have completed then you can use the following.

In the properties of the scenario: Set the user load to constant and to 500 users. Also set maximum test iteration to 0 (meaning no maximum). I would also set the think time between iteration to much longer than you expect the test run to take; this setting may not be needed but it avoids unexpected behaviours.

In the properties of the run settings there are two possibilities.
Either (1) set the test iterations to 500.
Or (2) set the run duration to long enough for all 500 tests to complete, but shorter than the think time between iteration in the scenario.